# Flex radioButton Set selected Value via ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I have a radioButton in an ItemRenderer of a List component.  I am trying to set the selected value of each radioButton based on a field in the dataprovider (SchoolList.Athletics_Fav).

These traces show the correct value:
trace("value: " +value.Athletics_Fav2);
trace("selectetText: " +selectText);

This one is not.
trace("btnSelect: "+radBtnPhone.selected);

Anyone have a suggestion as to how I can set radBtnPhone.selected to the dataprovider value (SchoolList.Athletics_Fav)?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
                ]]>
            </fx:Script>
        <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
                <s:fill><s:SolidColor color="0xffffff" /></s:fill>
            </s:Rect>
            <s:Line width="100%">
                <s:stroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke weight="1" color="0xd3d3d3"/>
                </s:stroke>
            </s:Line>
        </s:Group>
        <s:HGroup id="bigGrpPhone" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
            <s:HGroup id="grpPhone" gap="6" height="100%" width="95%" paddingLeft="2" paddingRight="2" paddingTop="2" verticalAlign="middle">
                <s:BitmapImage id="imgPhone" source="{data.SchoolImage}" width="70" height="70" />
                <s:Label id="schlNamePhone" maxDisplayedLines="1" width="100%" height="100%" text="{data.SchoolName}" verticalAlign="middle"/>
            </s:HGroup>
            <s:HGroup width="5%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
                <s:RadioButton width="50" id="radBtnPhone" styleName="myRadioButton" /> 
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:HGroup>
    </s:ItemRenderer>
    </fx:Component>
</s:itemRenderer>
```

Comment: Try listId.selectedItem.radBtnPhone.selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a simple solution and wanted to post here for others who may need it.  I created a Boolean variable (btnPhValue) and set it's value based on the value of the field AthleticsFavs in my SchoolList array.  Then I set the radioButton.selected value to the Boolean var I created.  Works Perfectly!

```
<s:List id="phoneList" width="100%" height="100%" contentBackgroundColor="0x0065a4" fontSize="20"
            dataProvider="{SchoolList}"  >
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:ItemRenderer >
                    <fx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                            override public function set data(value:Object):void 
                            {
                                super.data = value;
                                var selectPhText = value.AthleticsFavs;
                                var btnPhValue:Boolean;
                                radBtnPhone.group=outerDocument.radGrp;
                                if (selectPhText == 1)
                                    btnPhValue = true;
                                    else 
                                    btnPhValue = false;
                                radBtnPhone.selected = btnPhValue;
                            }
                        ]]>
                    </fx:Script>
                    <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
                        <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
                            <s:fill><s:SolidColor color="0xffffff" /></s:fill>
                        </s:Rect>
                        <s:Line width="100%">
                            <s:stroke>
                                <s:SolidColorStroke weight="1" color="0xd3d3d3"/>
                            </s:stroke>
                        </s:Line>
                    </s:Group>
                    <s:HGroup id="bigGrpPhone" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
                        <s:HGroup id="grpPhone" gap="6" height="100%" width="95%" paddingLeft="2" paddingRight="2" paddingTop="2" verticalAlign="middle">
                            <s:BitmapImage id="imgPhone" source="{data.SchoolImage}" width="70" height="70" />
                            <s:Label id="schlNamePhone" maxDisplayedLines="1" width="100%" height="100%" text="{data.SchoolName}" verticalAlign="middle"/>
                        </s:HGroup>
                        <s:HGroup width="5%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
                            <s:RadioButton width="50" id="radBtnPhone" styleName="myRadioButton" /> 
                            <!-- <MyComp:myRadioButton width="50" id="radBtnPhone" styleName="myRadioButton" /> -->
                        </s:HGroup>
                    </s:HGroup>
                </s:ItemRenderer>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:List>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    >

  <s:SkinnableDataContainer>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <mx:ArrayList id="SchoolList">
        <fx:Object SchoolName="Smith" Athletics_Fav="true" SchoolImage="./SchoolImage.png"/>
        <fx:Object SchoolName="Jones" Athletics_Fav="false" SchoolImage="./SchoolImage.png"/>
        <fx:Object SchoolName="Davis" Athletics_Fav="false" SchoolImage="./SchoolImage.png"/>
        <fx:Object SchoolName="Cooper" Athletics_Fav="true" SchoolImage="./SchoolImage.png"/>
    </mx:ArrayList>
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer>
            <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
                <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
                    <s:fill><s:SolidColor color="0xffffff" /></s:fill>
                </s:Rect>
                <s:Line width="100%">
                    <s:stroke>
                        <s:SolidColorStroke weight="1" color="0xd3d3d3"/>
                    </s:stroke>
                </s:Line>

            <s:HGroup id="bigGrpPhone" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
                <s:HGroup id="grpPhone" gap="6" height="100%" width="95%" paddingLeft="2" paddingRight="2" paddingTop="2" verticalAlign="middle">
                    <s:BitmapImage id="imgPhone" source="{data.SchoolImage}" width="70" height="70" />
                    <s:Label id="schlNamePhone" maxDisplayedLines="1" width="100%" height="100%" text="{data.SchoolName}" verticalAlign="middle"/>
                </s:HGroup>
                <s:HGroup width="5%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
                    <s:RadioButton width="50" id="radBtnPhone" styleName="myRadioButton" selected="{data.Athletics_Fav}"/>
                </s:HGroup>
            </s:HGroup>
            </s:Group>
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
  </s:SkinnableDataContainer>
</s:Application>
```

[image: Sample output]